# How can I find how Cryptowall infiltrated my work network?

Tags: virus-removal

Yesterday in the morning a colleague noticed that all files on the file server's Public folder were encrypted and had the

```
HELPME@FREESPEECHMAIL.ORG
```

text appended to each filename.

Public folder is visible by anyone in the wired local network and anyone can write/read/execute to this folder.

Despite this, file server seems to be okay; no high CPU Usage, no ransom messages or any weird alterations to the GUI. Also the server's local user files appear intact.

Not to mention that the file server cannot access the internet on purpose.

The problem is I cannot find how it got inside my network, since all computers appear to be fine. Except for the public folder, all files are good, no suspicious programs, all computers and file server run with ESET Smart Security, no high cpu usage and we only use one computer for emailing.

Any ideas on how can I find which computer was infected?

FYI There is no hardware firewall, all computers and mfps connect to a switch which gets internet connection from a One Access 150 router.

Comment: There is no answer than can be offered, really. Either you have the necessary infrastructure to trace the source (in which case you don't need an answer from us) or you don't (and we can't answer it). As for post-mortem analysis of a penetration, it is a field of study on its own: we can't possibly describe it in an answer. Voting to close as "too broad"

Comment: if you google it you have lot of info on this malware, maybe it has been made before you added securities, and you notice it just now

Comment: @Froggiz These computers have basic security. Each system has an administrator and a typical user. Windows updates are disabled.

Comment: If you really want to know get a specialist in computer forensics. But there is no guarantee that the original source will be detected. If you look at the various reports about specific attack the authors  often only speculate that the malware came in through a mail or some drive-by-download but don't know for sure either.

Answer (score 1):

You stated that you do not have a hardware firewall, there is no guarantee that the attack came from an internal machine. You could be exposing numerous ports to the internet.

A business level firewall would help prevent future attacks and most of these devices come with traffic logging capabilities that would aid the forensic investigation.

Most enterprise level AV solutions provide a central administration platform that pushes out new definition updates and logs all the infected files/machines. I'm most familiar with Trend's offering on this, however you would need to investigate each solution for yourself to check it fits your business needs.

---

For your immediate problem, you should isolate your network from the internet. Then isolate every machine (including servers and any BYOD laptops etc), run a standalone virus checker on every single machine. You should only reconnect machines to the network once they have been verified as clean.

Yes it is long and laborious but the plus side is you can put in a large claim for overtime this weekend.

Comment: "... You need an enterprise level AV/firewall solution. " - Just because it is called enterprise does not mean it as 100% secure or even better than a  personal AV. And even enterprise solutions differ a lot in the protection they offer.

Comment: Hence my follow up comment _"All the major vendors offer these, you would need to investigate each solution for yourself to check it fits your business needs."_

Comment: @SteffenUllrich in my opinion I think he suggests enterprise over personal  because as an administrator it would be much more easy to manage every instance from a single point, instead of having to configure them one by one.

Comment: After rereading the answer it occurred to me that @Burgi maybe meant that an enterprise firewall has better tracking on what's going on in the network so you could maybe find out how the malware entered the network. If this was the intent of the answer I suggest to be more explicit about it.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich edited my answer to be more explicit and clearer in what I meant.

Comment: @Burgi; This was the first thing I did when I arrived in the office, removed the cable from the router. I also used my own laptop with wireshark up and capturing all network traffic. I could not find anything suspicious, not to mention that av scan was clean. Forgot to add that a year ago the so-called police virus paid a visit to two of our client PCs. I will try to re-examine these systems tomorrow by putting their hard drives for an in-depth scan using a secure computer.

Comment: Also I am actually trying to find a good hardware firewall, but the annual cost for the license is just too much to bare. On the other hand given the circumstances I believe that I should asap use an old tower with 2 nics and put an open source firewall in it (wpfsense looks like good for the job).

Comment: My old company had great success with [Zyxel USGs](http://www.zyxel.com/uk/en/products_services/usg310_210_110.shtml?t=p) for our clients, I wasn't aware of any subscription costs but I didn't have anything to do with charging customers.